# Jquery mobile not persisting button state during navigation

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

When I go from one page to another in jquery , and use the browser back button to come back to the previous page, the tab state of the navbar items of the previous page are not persisted. Pls help

Comment: can somone answer this question pls

Comment: I hope you don't mind, it's a slow day so I am answering your other questions. :)

Answer (score 1):

Problem with jQuery Mobile and its **`navbar`** is in change page process. When you click on a **`navbar`** item you will immediately initialize a change page process and correct styles are not going to be applied correctly. But even if they are applied correctly, because of change page process they are not going to be propagated to the **`DOM`**.

In this case we need to do it manually. What you want to do is remove **`#href`** from your **`navbar`** li element or replace its value with #. Add a click event to that same li element.

When user clicks on a navbar tab javascript must remove all available classes called: **`ui-btn-active`** and **`ui-state-persist`**. If you have a navbar in every page then let them all have a same name because this javascript will need to go through all of them. When all those classes are removed then add them again but this time only to clicked/selected **`navbar`** item.

Now manually initialize jQuery Mobile changePage function and let it transit to a needed page. When changePage function ends its transition correc t navbar element will be selected (it will be seleced also on a previous page if you click a back button).

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/6h7gn/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 
    $(document).off('click', '#custom-navbar li').on('click', '#custom-navbar li', function(e){ 
        var selectedLi = $(this);
        $('#custom-navbar li').each(function( index ) {   
            var loopLi = $(this);
            if(loopLi.find('a').hasClass('ui-btn-active') || loopLi.find('a').hasClass('ui-state-persist')) { 
                loopLi.find('a').removeClass('ui-btn-activ').removeClass('ui-state-persist');
            }
            if(loopLi.attr('id') == selectedLi.attr('id')) {
                loopLi.find('a').addClass('ui-state-persist');   
            }
        });              
       setTimeout(function(){
            $.mobile.changePage( selectedLi.find('a').attr('data-href'), { transition: "slide"});
        },100);
    });       
});
```

Comment: This works fine on desktop browser and not on device. When I come back from another page, it shows all the tabs as selected, whichever i had previously selected. Below is my code which i had used in pageinit: var selectedItem = $(this);
  $(this).siblings().each(function(index){
    var loopItem = $(this);
             if(loopItem.find('a').hasClass('ui-btn-active')) {  
                 $(this).find('a').removeClass('ui-btn-active').removeClass('ui-state-persist');
             }
  });
  selectedItem.find('a').addClass('ui-btn-active').addClass('ui-state-persist');

Answer (score 0):

Did you use `class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist"` in your navbar to persist the tab state?

Check the example given in the [link](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/toolbars/footer-persist-a.html)